# Deserialize unknown nested json inside of known object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a situation where my web api takes in objects with a list of property values that have a bunch of static metadata and also a unique Value that can be anything.  For example, in my list of property values, there might be a property called start time, and this object will have an attribute called PropertyType, which will have a value of "System.DateTime", and the unique value will simply be "February 7th, 2017 11:00 AM" for example.  I also might have another property value that is called Backup folder, which will have a PropertyType with a value of "MyProject.MyNamespace.Folder" and the unique value will be a Folder object which I serialize and it looks like this

```
{\"$type\":\"MyProject.MyNamespace.Folder,\"m_FolderID\":6,\"m_FolderName\":\"Development\"}
```

Here is what the JSON looks like for a simple type:

```
{
  "propertyName": "AllowEntry",
  "categoryName": "User Interface",
  "displayName": "AllowEntry",
  "propertyId": 19,
  "typeName": "System.Boolean",
  "typeNameSSO": "",
  "toolTip": "",
  "description": "When set to true, the user is allowed to modify the value of the parameter when the job is manually submitted.",
  "editor": "",
  "mergeOption": 1,
  "sortOrder": 1,
  "inheritedFromType": 0,
  "inheritedFromId": 0,
  "inheritedFromName": null,
  "defaultValue": null,
  "currentValue": "true"
}
```

And here's what JSON looks like for a custom type

```
{
  "propertyName": "BackupFolder",
  "categoryName": "Query",
  "displayName": "Folder",
  "propertyId": 52,
  "typeName": "MyProject.MyNamespace.Folder",
  "typeNameSSO": "MyProject.MyNamespace.FolderSSO",
  "toolTip": "",
  "description": "Select a folder",
  "editor": "",
  "mergeOption": 1,
  "sortOrder": 6,
  "inheritedFromType": 0,
  "inheritedFromId": 0,
  "inheritedFromName": null,
  "defaultValue": null,
  "currentValue": "{\"$type\":\"MyProject.MyNamespace.Folder, \"m_FolderID\":6,\"m_FolderName\":\"Development\"}"
}
```

I want to know how to be able to look at these property values and Deserialize the currentValue information when it's nested Json instead of a simple value?

I've been trying to use a CustomCreationConverter, but I don't know how to capture the value of the property value object and start changing it.

This is my code:

```
public class PropertyValueJsonConverter : CustomCreationConverter<PropertyValue>
{
    public override PropertyValue Create(Type objectType)
    {            
        return new PropertyValue();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            object obj = new object();
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
            }
            return obj;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get a StackOverflowException with no explanation to the exception, and the existingObject value is null, and I'm not sure what else is going on.

Any ideas?

Comment: A stack overflow usually means there is an infinite recursion in your code. In Visual Studio you can set the debugger to break on thrown exceptions. At that point you can observe a few frames of the stack to identify which code is calling itself.

Comment: @GuillaumeCR - That's correct.  I finally realized that it was causing recursion because my call to Deserialize looks at my object and sees there is a place to ReadJson, which calls it to deserialize it.... and never stops doing that.  Now I just need to handle the object correctly.  Thanks!